# Various ways of calling C++ object destructor

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, explicit-destructor-call

A C++ object can be explicitly destructed using destructor call syntax (for non-class types pseudo-destructed). But it looks like that in addition to universally accepted syntax, almost any modern compiler supports its own ways of calling the destructor:

```
using T = int;
const int x = 1;
int main() { 
    x.~T();             //ok everywhere
    x.~int();           //#1: ok in MSVC only
    x.~auto();          //#2: ok in GCC only
    x.~decltype(x)();   //#3: ok in Clang and MSVC only
}
```

In addition to `x.~T()`, which works in all compilers, there are at least 3 other options, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/895bd9T5c

Are any of the options #1, #2 or #3 legal according to the standard or all of them are just extensions/bugs of the corresponding compilers?

Comment: all of them are either syntax error or undefined behavior

Comment: @bolov, when you say all of them, you mean the last three of the four?

Comment: @Jeffrey Explicitly calling a destructor on something that was not constructed with `placement-new` (or invoking the destructor via `delete` on something not constructed with `new)` is undefined. So technically, in this example, all 4 of them are undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jeffrey all 4. The 1st one is Undefined Behavior for the reason Remy Lebeau said.

Comment: That seems like an irrelevant detail to me. I meant to ask about the call to the destructor, _if_ it were a validly `new`ed object. And I guess OP meant that too. But yeah, ok. bolov, your comment would be much clearer if you called this out :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grammar doesn't allow (1) and (2), so those are illegal.
(See [`[expr.prim.id.dtor]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.dtor) -> [*id-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.general#nt:id-expression) -> [*unqualified-id*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#nt:unqualified-id) -> [*type-name*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#nt:type-name).)

The grammar does allow (3) though (... -> [*unqualified-id*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#nt:unqualified-id) -> [*decltype-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#nt:decltype-specifier)), and I don't see anything in `[expr.prim.id.dtor]` that would disallow using `decltype` in this scenario.

I tried several different things (making `T` a class type, making `x` dependent, etc), and in all cases GCC has rejected `~decltype(...)`. I'm assuming this is a GCC bug.

Comment: Why would #1 be illegal? `x` is an `int`, so it should be allowed to call `~int()` on it (provided `x` were created using [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), which it is not in this code, but that is irrelevant to the question asked).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Because, unless I'm missing something, the grammar doesn't allow `int` in this context.

Comment: `int *x = new(some_buffer) int; ... x->~int();` would be OK, but `int x; x.~int();` shoudn't be

Comment: @RemyLebeau Pseudo-destructors didn't end lifetime before C++20, so it made sense to ban them in non-generic code. The fact that they're still banned looks like a defect...

Comment: I reported a bug in GCC about `.~auto`: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102053. And it turned out that it was really an attempt to include that syntax in the standard, that was later rejected: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1586